# Creating a recursive options type

Tags: typescript

I'm building a library in typescript and I'd like to be able to accept a recursive options hash where there are a number of predefined keys with a specific type and everything else is a recursive version of the same structure.  I can't figure out how to do this generically without having overly general types (index types make this too accepting).

An example of what I'm going for:

```js
interface FilterOptions {
  age: number
  name: string
}

interface PaginationOptions {
  page: number
  per_page: number
}

type OptionsHash = {
  filters: RecursiveOptions<FilterOptions>
  pagination?: RecursiveOptions<PaginationOptions> 
}

let opts: OptionsHash = {
  filters: {
    age: 10,
    name: "Fred",
    foo: 10, // causes error
    friends: {
      age: 8,
      name: 234, // causes error
      pets: {
        name: 'fido'
      }
    },
    parents: {
      name: "Mom"
    }
  },
  pagination: {
    page: 3,
    friends: {
      page:1,
      per_page: 3
      pets: {
        per_page: 300
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me define `RecursiveOptions` in the above example.

Comment: Not really sure where `pets` and `parents` should come from..

Comment: Any of the keys with nested objects are entirely user defined, so the types should ideally not have to predefine them to take advantage.  Basically any key that isn't in the initial options list of the type interface should be of type `RecursiveOptions<Type>`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as why there would be *seemly random properties* thrown into the mix.  I believe the point of a strongly-typed language is to throw errors on the exceptions you've noted.  If you need user-defined options, they need to be separate from inner works of the class itself.

Comment: This is for an API client library which takes arbitrary nested payloads like the one I describe, so to make the library generic enough to support the apis, this is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have a natural representation for "any key except for the following".  That would require genuine [subtraction types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183) which TypeScript doesn't have.  So there's no way to represent `RecursiveOptions<FilterOptions>` as a concrete type.

The closest I can see to giving you the behavior you want is to make a type function which *verifies* that a type `R` matches what you want `RecursiveOptions<T>` to be:

```
interface FilterOptions {
  age: number
  name: string
}

interface PaginationOptions {
  page: number
  per_page: number
}

type VerifyRecursiveOptions<T, R> =
  R extends object ? { 
    [K in keyof R]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : VerifyRecursiveOptions<T, R[K]> 
  } : never

type OptionsShape = { filters: any, pagination?: any }

type VerifyOptionsHash<R extends OptionsShape> = {
  filters: VerifyRecursiveOptions<FilterOptions, R['filters']>
  pagination?: VerifyRecursiveOptions<PaginationOptions, R['pagination']>
}

const asOptionsHash = <T extends OptionsShape>(
  x: T & VerifyOptionsHash<T>
): T => x;
```

and you get errors where you expect them:

```
let opts = asOptionsHash({
  filters: {
    age: 10,
    name: "Fred",
    foo: 10, // causes error
    friends: {
      age: 8,
      name: 234, // causes error
      pets: {
        name: 'fido'
      }
    },
    parents: {
      name: "Mom"
    }
  },
  pagination: {
    page: 3,
    friends: {
      page: 1,
      per_page: 3,
      pets: {
        per_page: 300
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But this is complicated and possibly fragile.  Instead of trying to bend TypeScript to your will you might want to try using a more compiler-friendly type, like:

```
type TractablyRecursiveOptions<T> = T & { 
  recursivePart?: { [k: string]: TractablyRecursiveOptions<T> } 
};
```

In this case, instead of allowing *any extra key* to be added to `T`, you're only allowing just `recursivePart`.  This single well-known property can then have any keys you want.  But it requires refactoring of your `opts` value.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!